How to pass an object's method to a lambda-function?
A complex "calculator" is currently invoked like this:
            result = calculator.calc(a, b, extra);

Unfortunately, it may sometimes fail due to unrelated changes happening on the server. Synchronizing with different departments is difficult -- retrying is easier...
To that end, I implemented a retry lambda-function:
    auto retry = [](const auto& func, auto... args) {
        int attempts = 5;
        for (;;) try {
            return func(args...);
        }
        catch (const std::system_error& e) {
            /* Don't retry in case of a system_error */
            throw;
        }
        catch (const exception& e) {
            if (attempts-- == 0)
                throw; /* Give up and rethrow */
            Logging::log(Logging::Level::Warning,
                "%s. Retrying %d more times.", e.what(), attempts);
            sleep(2);
        }
    };

The above compiles, but, as I try to use it:
            result = retry(calculator.calc, a, b, extra);

I get an error from clang: reference to non-static member function must be called. GNU c++ flags the same line with invalid use of non-static member function.
Indeed, the calc() is a non-static method of the Calculator-class.
How would I make use of my new lambda?

Why is it a lambda instead of an ordinary named function?

Because the calling function is itself a template, and I didn't want to create a new one :)

In the lambda, replace func(args...) with std::invoke(func, args...). Now your lambda supports member function pointers as callable, in addition to function pointer/references, lambdas, and other function objects.
To pass the member function pointer, the syntax is:
result = retry(&Calculator::calc, &calculator, a, b, extra);

where Calculator is the class type of calculator. The extra argument &calculator is necessary to invoke the non-static member function on the specified object/instance of the class. std::invoke() knows how to handle it automatically.
You need to be a bit careful here. Because you pass the arguments by-value, if you write calculator instead of &calculator you will accidentally call the member function on a copy of calculator.

Generally, it would be better to pass the arguments by forwarding reference:
auto retry = [](auto&& func, auto&&... args) {

Then you can also call it as:
result = retry(&Calculator::calc, calculator, a, b, extra);

std::invoke() knows how to handle both pointers and references to the class instance when invoking member function pointers.
Note however that, because you potentially call func() multiple times, you shouldn't std::forward the forwarding references into the call.

Also, as a side note, if you want to keep retry generic, it is not enough to catch std::exception. There is no requirement that exceptions must be derived from std::exception. That's just a convention used in the standard library, and sometimes by other libraries.
A fall-back catch block for all other exceptions should look like this:
catch(...)
{
    // do something
}


An alternative is to pass calculator in the lambda's capture list, rather than as an argument.

What are the pros -- and cons -- of doing that, @Peter?

AS I said, it's an alternative.  Functionally, achieves the same thing.  Normal trade-offs between capturing (a reference to) an object in a capture list, versus passing it later as an argument when calling the lambda.     Decision needs to be based on considerations like whether the same object must be used every time, or a different object needs to be passed each time.

You might pass directly a lambda:
retry([&](){ return calculator.calc(a, b, extra); });


Sorry, I don't understand. Could you elaborate -- perhaps, with a more complete example?

I meant, simply replace result = retry(calculator.calc, a, b, extra); by above code result = retry([&](){ return calculator.calc(a, b, extra); });. that lambda would be the callable without extra args.
